# jquery - $.map - returning element not appending properly

Tags: jquery

using $.map function i am looping a object and appending the element i make. but my case, i am getting the console info properly, but finally returning object only appending, what is the issue in my code?

my code :

```
  $('body').append(
 $.map(val.fields, function (val, i) {
     var element;
     if (val.label) {
         element = $('<label />', {
             text: val.label
         });
         console.log(element); //properly consoles 3 lables but not appending why?
     }
     if (val.type) {
         element = val.type === 'text' || val.type === 'submit' ? $('<input />', {
             type: val.type,
             name: val.name,
             value: val.value,
             id: val.vlaue
         }) : val.type === 'select' ? $('<select />', {
             name: val.name
         }) : '';
         console.log(element); // properly console 3 element and only this is appending
     }

     return element;
 }))
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what "but finally returning object only appending" means? Are you saying you create multiple objects but only the last one created gets appended?

Comment: yes. i want to append all both labels and input element. but i a getting the type of elements appended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the type of the objects returned from the call to `$.map`.

If you change your map call to `return element[0]` (The actual dom element created rather than the wrapped jQuery object) then it works:

```
$('body').append(
     $.map(val.fields, function (val, i) {
         var element;
         if (val.label) {
             element = $('<label />', {
                 text: val.label
             });
             console.log(element); //properly consoles 3 lables but not appending why?
         }
         if (val.type) {
             element = val.type === 'text' || val.type === 'submit' ? $('<input />', {
                 type: val.type,
                 name: val.name,
                 value: val.value,
                 id: val.vlaue
             }) : val.type === 'select' ? $('<select />', {
                 name: val.name
             }) : '';
             console.log(element); // properly console 3 element and only this is appending
         }

         return element[0]; // <----- Added [0] here
     })
)
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/nhds6/

This is assuming that there will always be an element. You probably want to add some error handling if that isn't the case.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct. now the body appends 3 labels and 1 input type, instead of 3 input types...

Answer (score 1):

You probably misinterpreted what map does.

> The $.map() method applies a function to each item in an array or object and maps the results into a new array.

You might want to consider adding a jQuery collection:

```
var collection = $();


$.map(val.fields, function (val,i) {
    var element;
    if(val.label){
        element = $('<label />',{text:val.label});
        collection.add(element);
    }
    if(val.type) {
        element =   val.type === 'text' || val.type === 'submit' ? $('<input />',{
            type:val.type,
            name:val.name,
            value:val.value,
            id:val.vlaue
        }) :
        val.type === 'select' ? $('<select />',{name:val.name}) : '';
        collection.add(element);
    }
});

$('body').append(collection);
```

The main difference to the answer of user338128 is that you don't need multiple loops.

Comment: If you're not using the return from `$.map()` it might as well be `$.each()`. I'd suggested moving the `collection.add(element)` to the end of _both_ `if` blocks, because both blocks can create elements...

Comment: Good points. `collection.add()` is at the very end, after the if statements so the elements are always added. No need to write it twice.

Comment: What I mean is that if the `val.label` and `val.type` properties are both set _on the same iteration_, the first `if` would create an element and then the second `if` would _also_ create an element - but only the second would actually be added to the collection. (Maybe that won't ever happen for the data the OP is using, but since we haven't been shown that data...)

Comment: You are right. It is unlikely but I moved the add calls into the if blocks, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function that you pass to `$.map` can return only one thing at a time, `element`, but with your two `if` statements in a row you potentially try to create two things - but if you do create two elements only the second one ends up in the `element` variable that you return.

If `val.label` and `val.type` are both set and `val.label` should take precedence then change the second `if` to an `else if`.

If you need to be able to create both at once then perhaps `$.map` isn't the best way to do it.